# Zariski closure of an algebraic linear group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, zariski-topology

Let $G$ and $H$ algebraic linear groups and $\phi : G \to H$ a regular group homomorphism. I wonder if $\overline{\phi(G)}$ (the Zariski closure of $\phi(G)$) is again a subgroup and how this could be proven. First of all, I know Zariski closure $\overline{Z}$ of a set $Z$ is defined as $\overline{Z} = V(I(Z))$. I imagine this definition is also valid for algebraic linear groups, since $G$ is an affine variety. However, I can’t seem to find a strategy for this proof: any ideas?

Comment: Is $H$ another algebraic group? Is $\phi$ a group homomorphism? Which algebraic formalism are you using (schemes, or something more elementary?)

Comment: Thanks, I just edited. I am not using schemes, I am studying "classic" algebraic geometry

Comment: The image is automatically closed. Are you not aware of this?

Comment: No, I'm not. Why is that?

Comment: @cip It’s not like totally obvious. You can see, for example, Theorem 5.39 in Milne’s published book on algebraic groups. It comes down to some kind of easy study of group actions and minimal orbits, but I’ll let you ready about that yourself.

Comment: @AlexYoucis are you considering [this reference](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/iAG200.pdf#page30)? If so, it seems to me that you’re referring to a different edition, or I may fail to see how Theorem 5.39 here is useful for our purpose

Comment: Actually, I found a proof of the fact that $\phi(G)$ is closed somewhere else, but it uses precisely that $\overline{\phi(G)}$ is a group

Comment: @cip I mean the proof in Milne doesn't, at least not explicitly, but if you really just wanna know that you just need to note that since $m:H\times H\to H$ is continuous that since $m(\phi(G),\phi(G))\subseteq \overline{\phi(G)}$ that $m(\overline{\phi(G)},\overline{\phi(G)})\subseteq \overline{\phi(G)}$. The reason is that $\overline{\phi(G)\times \phi(G)}=\overline{\phi(G)}\times \overline{\phi(G)}$ and https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuity_Defined_by_Closure

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. Do I have to notice something similar for $i : H \to H$ defined such that $i(h) = h^{-1}$?

Comment: @cip that’s right.